# What DLL files do cmd use when rendering the text

Tags: dll, cmd, rendering

I know that cmd `render` the text with `colors` bequas when you select dark colored text the `colors` get inverted to a new spectrum.

What core `DLL` file does `cmd` use while rendering the text buffer?

List of dll files that cmd uses.

```
ntdll.DLL
KERNEL32.DLL
KERNELBASE.DLL
GDI32.DLL
USER32.DLL
msvcrt.DLL
IMM32.DLL
OLEAUT32.DLL
combase.DLL
MSCTF.DLL
RPCRT4.DLL
uxtheme.DLL
dwmapi.DLL
comctl32.DLL
ole32.DLL
sechost.DLL
kernel.appcore.DLL
CRYPTBASE.DLL
bcryptPrimitives.DLL
SHCORE.DLL
MSVCR90.DLL
allochook-x86_64.DLL
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: I am not sure how someone would answer this without reverse engineering the product or gaining access to source code. Ultimately, one would think that it must go through `gdi32.dll`. What problem does having this information solve?

Comment: If i can get the `pointer` of the `rendering` method i could by `c++ / java / asm` change the method to use more `color`. #Overcompliceted @liturgist